# pine pitch, lots of it

Tags: pines

We have 2 big pine trees in our backyard that give off a lot of pitch.  My dog is covered in it, my shoes get covered in it, its everywhere!!!!!

What is the best ground for reducing the pitch's advancement on my life?

grass, gravel, pavement, etc...

today its mostly dirt and some really short grass stubs but this coming summer we will be redoing it and I'm trying to start the planning now.

Comment: why don't you just cut them down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you check your trees thoroughly, or get an arborist to do it - they should not be leaking pitch at all, and especially not in excessive amounts. The fact that they are indicates a problem of some sort - maybe canker, fusarium infection, or something less dangerous (in terms of compromising the tree from a safety point of view) such as an insect infestation, something like scale or pine aphids. This link https://www.hunker.com/12560959/what-causes-sap-to-drip-from-a-pine-tree might be helpful.

Comment: They are ponderosa pines very big and tall.  From what i hear from neighbors its a common problem around here.  but i will do some more research and find an arborist to consult.  thanks.

Comment: They've probably all got the same infestation....which means it'll be difficult to resolve unless everyone treats the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: i held on on marking this as the answer since it is more of a reason then an answer, but since there hasnt been any others i will now.  regardless though the arborist came today and there isnt much I can do.  Im in central OR and its the pandora moth that is the culprit.  The arborist said these moths do not kill or reduce the life span of the tree and so they are usually just left alone (or the tree is removed if the pitch is too much to deal with).

Comment: Interesting,  never heard of Pandora moth, but then I'm in the UK. Curious about your statement re 'reason' and 'answer' - surely the reason something's happening is also an answer, isn't it? Even if the reason/answer isn't one you want to hear, its an answer if its accurate, I'd have thought. Just curious as to what exactly you mean....

Comment: what is the best ground material?  grass, gravel, concrete, dirt.  idk this is just an example but:  "dirt or gravel is best because once the sap gets into the dust, it reduces its stickyness" or "grass because the sap sinks to the ground and so the raised grass blades means you can walk on it without collecting it".  basically what ground is best when your getting alot of sap from your trees.

Comment: Makes no odds what you use - copious amounts of pitch will make a sticky mess on any surface. I suppose concrete might make it easier to flush it off with the hose and a stiff broom.